# how to design first letter in label?

Tags: css

I want to design any one letter in label which the user will identify it as a short cut key to move on. There is a psudo element called :first-letter for paragraph tag. In the same way is there any to attain what i expected..Pls help me.

Answer (score 9):

You're having trouble because the :first-letter pseudo class will **only work for block level elements**.

You need to do something like this for it to work:

Example HTML

```
<label>This is a label</label>
```

Example CSS

```
label {
    display: block;
}

label:first-letter {
    color: red;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pBU49/

Comment: `:first-letter` also works with `inline-block`.